# Installed Ubuntu with "Erase Disk" option, all partitions deleted

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-10, testdisk

I used "Erase Disk & Install Ubuntu" option while installing Ubuntu, thinking that it will erase just the C:\ drive on which my previous OS(Win 10) was installed. After installation I found that only one partition is created in Ubuntu and all other partitions D:\ and E:\ are lost as well. Tried 'testdisk' but it is also not listing deleted partitions. It is just listing one partition that is current one. Please let me know how can I access the deleted D:/ and E:/ partitions.

Answer (score 1):

"Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" completely wipes the target drive(the one you are installing to) and allocates the entire drive for Ubuntu. Unfortunately, all the data on the drive has been overwritten, and your partitions are unrecoverable. You will have to restore from backups.